# How do I implement unbound data binding in Lightning controllers

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura-attribute

I know in Lightning components I can use {#v.attr} to provide independent usage of data.
But how about JavaScript, is there something similar I could do when setting a components attribute?

I'm doing this:

```
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var originalData = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
        cmp.set("v.changingData", originalData);
        cmp.set("v.originalData", originalData); <--- this needs to be unbound
    });
```

But whenever I update v.changingData in my component, v.originalData will be changed too.
Is there something Lightning provides? Or any clone similar functionality?
Of cause I'm not willing to parse the JSON twice.

Comment: Looks like I'm the only who doesn't understand the question. Why your originalData attribute would be changed too if you don't execute the second cmp.set of your function?

Comment: Looks like you want to save the original data for later. You want to copy "by value" but Lightning behaves as it is copying "by reference"?

Comment: @MartinLezer If I don't execute the second, it would be empty?!

Comment: @RobertSösemann Ooooh never tried that. Does Lightning add a binding because of the originalData variable reference?

Comment: @Basti By searching the web, I found that you can clone an object with a little trick: `var originalDataClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalData));`. Could you try to set your `originalData` attribute with this new variable?

Comment: @MartinLezer I guess it would be more efficient to just parse it twice instead of adding an extra stringify

Comment: @Basti I guess I'm dumb and you're right.

Comment: This [PropertyReferenceValue .evaluate](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/f49e9d1db9280ea37e4d6a34f7c9167c6ae95044/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/value/PropertyReferenceValue.js#L43) function looks like it might give you  the underlying value but as (AFAIK) undocumented API it can't be used.

Comment: As @RobertSösemann says - you should copy this variable to a different variable by value and not by reference - you can again `JSON.parse` your returned data, or you can use  [var originalData2 = Object.assign({}, originalData);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: @ItaiShmida this will solve my problem, feel free to add an answer with both solutions, so I can accept it. I prefer the "assign", because I assume it is more efficient, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobertSösemann says - the variable is copied by reference, this is why a change in it is reflected in both attributes. To solve this you should copy the value by value and not by reference.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Call again `var originalData2 = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());`  - this would create another variable with the original data as value not as a reference.
2. Use the JavaScript [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method on the originalData: `var originalData2 = Object.assign({}, originalData);`

I assume that the second solution should probably be best as it is not using the JSON parser which can be 'expensive'.

Comment: surprisingly Object.assign didn't work :( It returned the object by reference.

Comment: If your original data is nested, Object.assign will clone the top level object but everything inside will be by reference. The best way to do this is going to be to be parsing the data twice. That or storing the original data as a string and parsing it as needed later. How bad in the performance? I assume it's just done the one time on server response.

Comment: In that case, and with @wellmstein's comment, I think that the best would be the first option